# Create a large file in windows with information

Tags: windows, file, large-files, notepad

Is it possible to create a huge file (320GB or bigger) to use as a wiping tool? I.E. a file that contains just binary 1's or a text file containing all jumbled up ASCII (the sort of stuff that gets churned out of the printer when there has been a spool error). Would it be possible to create it in Microsoft Notepad?

Comment: You certainly will need another tool. Notepad begins to choke with a few Megabytes

Comment: What on  earth would you need a 320GB file for?!? In all of the many tools I've used (and written), including tools for large operating systems, there has *never* been a need for a file larger than 25GB.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fsutil` like this to create an arbitrarily sized file:

```
fsutil file createnew C:\fatboy.tmp SIZE_IN_BYTES
```

[image]

It will be binary zeroes, but they cover stuff just as well as ones - all bits are opaque really.

Another way is to put your unwanted disk in the freezer for a week, then to put it in boiling water for a few hours and finally put a high-speed steel drill bit through it in several places - makes them awfully hard to read and is quite therapeutic!!!

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can use ImageMagick's `convert` to create a PNG image full of random noise like this:

```
convert -size 14000x14000 xc: +noise Random random.png
```

which will result in a 1GB file called `random.png`. You can then make it arbitrarily big using COPY like this:

```
copy /b random.png+random.png+random.png+random.png 4x.png
```